# Exercise 1.15. from Exercise in Classical Ring Theory by T.Y. Lam

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Exercise 1.15. from *Exercises in Classical Ring Theory* by T.Y. Lam:

> Let $A = \mathbb{ C}[x; σ]$, where $σ$ denotes complex conjugation on$ \mathbb{ C}$.
>
> (a) Show that $Z(A) =\mathbb{ R}[x^2]$.
>
> (b) Show that $A/A · (x^2 + 1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{ H}$, the division ring of real quaternions.
>
> (c) Show that $ A/A · (x^4 + 1)$ is isomorphic to $M_2(\mathbb{ C})$.

What is meaning of $A · (x^2 + 1)$ ?

For (a): $x^2a = σ^2 (a)x^2 = ax^2$ for all $ a ∈ \mathbb{ C}$.
This shows that $ \mathbb{ R}[x^2] ⊆ Z(A)$.

Comment: And if you want help in b and c, what's your question there?